# yii setflash is not working when using redirect

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Hye there i have a problem i've design my website using yii framework and now when user register i want to show something like registration successful and redirect to log in page. Unfortunately it keep redirect to log in page without showing any message. Below is my code for user controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new User;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(array('profile'));
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Registration successful. Please login');

        }

    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

This is the code for my log in

```
public function actionProfile()
{
    $model=$this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
    unset($model->password);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

This is the code for my access ruler

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('register','create'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('profile', 'history', 'recommendation','view'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete','update','create','index'),
            'expression' => 'Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()'
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

This is in my actionview

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [yii setflash not working in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434435/yii-setflash-not-working-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Use `return` because it stopped process.

```
return $this->redirect();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out my mistake:

instead of this:

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Registration successful. Please login');
    $this->redirect(array('profile'));
```

I should do like this:

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Registration successful. Please login');
      $this->redirect(array('/site/login'));
```

Answer (score 0):

untested but:

```
 if(isset($_POST['User']))
{
    $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
    if($model->save()) {
        $this->redirect(array('profile'));
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Registration successful. Please login');

    }
```

should be

```
 if(isset($_POST['User']))
{
    $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
    if($model->save()) {
     Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Registration successful. Please login');
        $this->redirect(array('profile'));
```

You also need to check for the flash message in your view to display it
        }

Comment: Right now what i can do is i just refresh my page where i insert $this->refresh() below my yii setflash...if u guys found the solution for this please let me know....

Comment: No you haven't. As I said to you, you need to check in your view file views/user/view.php you need to check for the existence of the flash method `Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')):`

Answer (score 0):

It happened the same, and it turned out that was not going to the "if" because it is not being fulfilled and why not show the message or redirected to another view.

In short, it could perhaps be because you are not fulfilling the condition. ;)