# yii setflash not working in php

Tags: php, yii

Hye there i have a problem i've design my website using yii framework and now when user register i want to show something like registration successful and redirect to log in page. Unfortunately it keep redirect to log in page without showing any message. Below is my code for user controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new User;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(array('profile'));
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Registration successful. Please login');

        }

    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

This is the code for my log in

```
public function actionProfile()
{
    $model=$this->loadModel(Yii::app()->user->id);
    unset($model->password);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

This is the code for my access ruler

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('register','create'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('profile', 'history', 'recommendation','view'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete','update','create','index'),
            'expression' => 'Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()'
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you checking for the flash on the redirected page?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $this->redirect(array('profile'));
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Registration successful. Please login');
```

You redirect before you set flash... instead try:

```
    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'Registration successful. Please login');
    $this->redirect(array('profile'));
```

Comment: Fyi i have tried ur code before its not working it redirect but not showing the msg...now what i did i just refresh my page instead of redirect...if u have solution for this please let me know

Answer (score -1):

In your view add this:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('success')): ?>

<div class="success">
    <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('success'); ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```